# Pass the arraylist from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I am trying to pass the complete arraylist from one activity to another.

i have tried like this way..

```
arraylist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();


    Intent i= new Intent(ListActivity.this,search.class);
               i.putExtra("arraylist", arraylist);
               startActivity(i);
```

Could somebody help me out  @thanks

Comment: what error do you get ? Why do you pass Object, as values for your hashmap? Object is not serializable. Post the original code

Comment: @blackbelt i ma receiving empty array!!

Comment: post the original code

Comment: @blackbelt actually i am getting the data from webservice and try to pass the complete arraylist to another activity..

Comment: Are any errors appearing in LogCat?

Comment: @priya whitout the code nobody can tell you what's goin on

Comment: @blackbelt ok..let me show you the complete code

Comment: @PhilApplegate let me add what i am getting

Comment: @blackbelt i am getting the data but not complete arraylist..

Comment: what data are you getting? In what way is the arraylist incomplete?

Comment: @PhilApplegate actually i need the complete data for search functionality...but due to pagination i am not getting the complete data..

Comment: please see the update to my answer

Comment: [**Please See this Blog. This Can Help You**](http://startandroiddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-pass-boolean-int-string-integer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work because the `Object` class in Java is not serializable. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600213/why-doesnt-java-lang-object-implement-the-serializable-interface) for an explanation as to why.

The `Intent.putExtra()` method requires a type that implements the serializable interface, Object does not implement this so consequently it will not work. I would suggest rather than having a `HashMap<String,Object>` you replace the Object with a more specific type that implements the Serializable interface. See this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm) for how to do this.

**UPDATE**

If the data you are passing is large there could be a fairly significant overhead associated with serializing and deserializing. Consequently it might be worth using a Static Singleton class to store the arraylist. The code sample below shows how you could implement this:

```
public class DataStore {
    private static final DataStore instance = new DataStore ();
    private arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

    //Private constructor
    private DataStore () {}

    //Class is only accessible through this method
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    //Accessors for your data
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> getArrayList()
    {
         return arraylist;
    }

    private void setArrayList(ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> value)
    {
         arraylist = value;
    }
}
```

For reference here is a [tutorial](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/22/singleton-design-pattern-in-java/) on static singletons.

Comment: I agree, the singleton or a static field is the best way to store shared data in the same process. If your activities lives in different processes, then mesage passing is the only reasonable way and you need to marshall your data.